# Facebook JS SDK for Open Graph: Logout not working!

Tags: facebook, logout, facebook-opengraph

For some reason when I call `FB.logout();`, the user does not actually get logged out of Facebook.

Why might this be? No js errors get thrown, and I can step through the code as it runs through the SDK... it just doesn't successfully log out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the `fb-root` DIV tag first, then call `FB.init()` and then `FB.logout()`

**Example Usage:**

```
FB.logout(function(){
  window.location = 'path/url here';
});
```

Alternatively, you should redirect to this url logout:

```
www.facebook.com/logout.php?app_key=KEY&session_key=SESSION&next=REDIRECT_URL
```

Comment: Thank you thank you. I had removed the fb-root as part of the post login js function. Didn't know I still needed it.

Comment: I may sound idiot to ask this question, but could you please tell me how i get this SESSION_KEY ?

I am using PHP SDK and want to logout user as     $myURL="www.facebook.com/logout.php?    app_key=".$config['appId']."&session_key=SESSION&next=REDIRECT_URL";
header("location:$myURL");

Answer (score -2):

You need to have a valid access token when you call `FB.logout`. Don't remove the **`fbs_*`** cookies on your own. `FB.logout` will do this itself.

Comment: I believe the OP does not mention deleting any cookie. Besides, an answer has already been accepted. Why revive an old thread which already has its solution?